# Snowflake privileges

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a user and role like
user : ali
role : analyst

i have granted this role and user to accountadmin and systemsecurity roles.

And i granted usage permission on database Admin and custom schemas of database Admin to role analyst.

Also granted select permission on table "Admin.schema.table1" to role analyst.

But when i tried to execute the below query
"Admin.information_schema.procedures" under role "analyst" showing empty table.

when i execute "Admin.information_schema.procedures" with role "accountadmin" it is showing results.

why i am getting empty resultset with analyst custom-role ?

Answer (score 2):

Since Procedure is a Schema object, apart from USAGE privilege on database Admin, you need to [grant](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html) access on both the Schema "SCHEMA" as well as any target Procedure.

You can do this by running the following statements, as accountadmin:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ADMIN.SCHEMA TO ROLE ANALYST;
GRANT USAGE ON PROCEDURE ADMIN.SCHEMA.<PROCEDURE_NAME> TO ROLE ANALYST;
```

Now that you do have access to the target procedure(s), you can query it in information_schema.procedures View.

Comment: thank you Mansoor.If any new procedure is added in future then i have to give permissions to it manually.How can i handle that situation everytime giving privilege to new procedures manually?

Comment: You can handle the privileges on future procedures in a schema, using the FUTURE grants, as shown below:

GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA "ADMIN"."SCHEMA" TO ROLE ANALYST;

Comment: thank you it is working.
But i have one more doubt , what about the already existed procedures ?
Do i need to grant permission to each by name or is there any way to give privilege at a time to all already existed procs ?

Comment: i tried by executing a procedure named demo in public schema.
public schema has already procedures.
when i tried to get procedures it is giving only demo procedure not giving already existed procs.
Do i need to grant individually ?

Comment: Yes, one way is to explicitly grant usage on each one of the procedures. If you would like to do it in one go, for all the procedures in a schema, you can do it by running the following:
GRANT USAGE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA ADMIN.SCHEMA TO ROLE ANALYST;

Comment: Thank you for quick response . It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Given the Snowflake documentation on [information_schema.procedures VIEW](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/procedures.html)

> The view only displays objects for which the current role for the
> session has been granted access privileges. The view does not honor
> the MANAGE GRANTS privilege and consequently may show less information
> compared to a SHOW command when both are executed by a user who holds
> the MANAGE GRANTS privilege.

So because your **analyst** role doesn't have privilege on any procedures in the schema it shows an empty result.
When you query the view with the **accountadmin** role which got privilege on everything in your account then you can see the procedures this role has privilege on.

You need to grant USAGE privilege on the procedure and of course USAGE on schema containing the procedure.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_db.admin TO ROLE analyst;
GRANT USAGE ON PROCEDURE my_db.admin.my_proc TO ROLE analyst;
```

and for procedures not existing yet

```
USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;
GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA my_db.admin TO ROLE analyst;
```

Comment: thank you CMe , may i know how to assign privileges on procedures to analyst role

Comment: i just need select privilege to get procedures by analyst role

Comment: Edited my answer above to provide GRANT queries needed.

Comment: Thank you.But everytime how can i give permission to a procedure with it's name.is there any way to give privileges automatically for procs that will be created in future ?

Comment: For giving permissions on procedures which doesn't exist yet you'll have to use GRANT on FUTURE objects (and use SECURITYADMIN role for this).
Edited with this.

Comment: but the issue is already existed procs.
Do i need to give permission to each proc by name to analyst role ?

Comment: If you want to give permissions on all existing procedures in a schema you can use GRANT USAGE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA my_db.admin TO ROLE analyst;

Comment: Thank you for quick response . It helps me a lot.